# How to add all Teachers from Office365 to all Teams as owners in Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-teams

I need to add all teachers from Office 365 to existing Teams in Teams app/service to be owners of all existing Teams.
What i have done:

1. Exported list of teachers from Msol:

```
    Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "STANDARDWOFFPACK_FACULTY"}| select userprincipalname | Export-Csv "filename.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

2. Tried few combinations for example:

```
    Import-Csv "filename.csv" | foreach{Get-Team | Add-TeamUser -Role Owner
```

but i miss "something" for use properly each user with each team, so i don't know how to construct and in what order this commands or maybe there is other easier method?
At the end/start of that i should remove this teachers from regular members of this teams because i observed that when user is as member and owner, then team disappear from list in client app for that user.
This is my first question here, so maybe i make some mistakes in creating this question or it is to easy for many of you, but please be easy for me too xD.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Not working with teams, but as per the documentation it should be something like this...

```
# using your exported csv file...
foreach ($user in Import-Csv "filename.csv")
{
    $GroupId = (Get-Team -User $User.UserPrincipalName).GroupId
    Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupId -User $User.UserPrincipalName -Role Owner
}
```